# I need to generate random 1s and 0s in excel but the 1s should have a certain % composition of the total numbers generated

Tags: random

I need help in excel please....
I want to generate random numbers between 0 and 1 (integers) running from left to right per row in an excel spreadsheet. I have a total of 56 rows and 85 columns. However the generation of 1's must be linked to a percentage of occurrence. So for example: in row 1, 1's and 0's should be randomly generated but the number 1 should occur 0.813% of the time. In row 4, 1's and 0's should be randomly generated but the number 1 should occur 23.98% of the time (the remainder of each row should obviously be 0's). The sum of all the % of occurrence values is equal to 100% but are in no particular order.

Hope you can help (seems i cant upload an image of the spreadsheet)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not familar with Excel much, but the basic approach would be to generate a random floating point number evenly distributes between 0 and 1 (that should be easy), and then compare that with a "trigger value", for example 0.2398. If it is lower, then count as "1" otherwise count as "0". That should be doable with an Excel function. In your case, that trigger value would be looked up from a cell in each row with your probability configuration.